# Probability distribution for putting balls in boxes in a correlated way

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm looking for help finding a probability distribution:

Right now I have a problem where I have N indistinguishable balls, which I need to put into K indistinguishable boxes, each of which can hold M balls.  However, I want to be able to control how evenly the balls are distributed (i.e. so I can make them more uniform than random, or more likely to be clumped into a few urn than random).

Is there a probability distribution that will give me something like this?

Thanks!

Simon

Comment: Let me know if my understanding of your problem is correct and if so please accept it for future users. If not it would be great if you could clarify :)

Comment: I think you have the right idea, but the main thing I was wondering if there is a named statistical distribution that would give me something like this. If not, I will go with something like what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt to control it as follows:

1. Each time you choose a box to put a ball in you sample from the the distribution over boxes $P(B)$
2. Let $P(B)$ initialise as a uniform probability distribution such that $P(B=b_i) = \frac{M}{KT}$, start T=M
3. Make a sample from the distribution, hence picking a box (lets say $b_x$)
4. Now before repeating step 3, subtract 1 from the numerator of $b_x$ and and subtract 1 from T

The expected distribution over the boxes will be uniform. This of course does not mean you will get an even distribution on any single run, it is merely an expectation. It is very simple to come up with other rulings that produce the same expectation. Give it a try! :)